# problem with pandas drop_duplicates removing empty values

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

Im using drop_duplicates to remove duplicates from my dataframe based on a column, the problem is this column is empty for some entries and those ended being removed to is there a way to make the function ignore the empty value.
here is an example

```
    Title                  summary                  
0   TITLE A                summaryA       
1   TITLE A                summaryB  
2                          summaryC       
3                          summaryD
```

using this

```
data.drop_duplicates(subset ="TITLE", 
                     keep = 'first', inplace = True)
```

I get a result like this:

```
    Title                  summary                  
0   TITLE A                summaryA        
2                          summaryC
```

but since last two rows are not duplicates i want to keep them. is there a ways for drop_duplicates to ignore empty values?

Answer (score 0):

Fill missing values with the index number? Maybe not the prettiest way but it works

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Title':['TITLE A', 'TITLE A', None, None], 'summary':['summaryA', 'summaryB', 
    'summaryC', 'summaryD']}
    )

df['_id'] = df.index
df['_id'] = df['_id'].apply(str)
df['Title2'] = df['Title'].fillna(df['_id'])  

df.drop_duplicates(subset ="Title2", keep = 'first')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
data.drop_duplicates(subset ="TITLE", 
                     keep = 'last', inplace = True)
```